# How do I determine which events occurred significantly more during a certain operating mode?

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, chi-squared-distribution

I have data of $N$ different event $E_n$ occurring at times $t_{n,i}$. So any event $E_n$ could have occurred any number of times.

Normally the system operates in operating mode A. Sometimes the system operates in operating mode B. I have recorded during which times this operating mode was valid. I.e. some of the occurrences $t_{n,i}$ were during operating mode A, and some were during operating mode B.

I want to know which events occurred significantly more during operating mode B, compared to operating mode A.

E.g.:

| Event | occurrences in A | occurrences in B | total occurrences |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $E_1$ | 20 | 20 | 40 |
| $E_2$ | 30 | 5 | 35 |
| $E_3$ | 10 | 50 | 60 |
| $E_4$ | 50 | 15 | 65 |
| total | 110 | 90 | 200 |

Where operating mode **A was active for 10 days** in total, and operating mode **B for only 2**.

**Chi-Squared**

I thought I could do this with a Chi-Squared test. However, I don't know how to incorporate the fact that operating mode B was of shorter length than operating mode A. (If I simply ignore this fact and follow the math as explained on e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test), I believe that I'm assuming that the total amount of occurrences during A and B is proportional to their respective lengths. In the example above, 11 events per day occur in mode A, while 45 events per day occur in mode B. How do we account for that in Chi-Square?)

**Question**: What is the most appropriate way of determining which events occur significantly more during operating mode B?